# Webpack only displays 'App ready'. but does not display components. How to fix it?

Tags: html, angular, webpack, angular-material, webpack-dev-server

I have an application for Angular 7. I added a Webpack. Configuration:
webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  context: __dirname +'/',
  entry: {
    'polyfills': '/src/polyfills.ts',
    'app': '/src/main.ts'
  },
  output:{
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),     // путь к каталогу выходных файлов - папка public
    libraryTarget: "system",
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/index.html': 'http://localhost:4200',
    },
    inline: false,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 4200,
    open: true
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: "single", // enable "runtime" chunk
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendor",
          chunks: "all"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  module:{
    rules:[   //загрузчик для ts
      {
        test: /\.ts$/, // определяем тип файлов
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: { configFileName: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json') }
          } //,
          //'angular2-template-loader'
        ]
      }, {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },{
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[fullhash].[ext]',
        }
      },{
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },{
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app'),
        loader: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './src')),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './src')),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          // global app config object
          config: JSON.stringify({
            apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4200'
          })
        }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css"
    }),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/, path.join(__dirname, './src'))
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "kafka-data-exchange-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "serve": "ng serve --port 4200",
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "4": "^0.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.16",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-webpack-inline-source-plugin": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.4.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "systemjs": "^6.3.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "underscore": "^1.12.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.150",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.3.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "concurrently": "4.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^8.1.1",
    "html-loader": "2.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "loader-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.31.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^1.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <base href="/">
  <title>Kafka Data Exchange</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">-->
</head>

<body>
<mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
<ng-app></ng-app>
</body>

</html>
```

I run:

> npx webpack

as a result I get:
[image]

then I run:

> npm run dev

but I don't get what I expected
[image]

but I get a blank page with url http: // localhost: 4200 / webpack-dev-server /

Everything works fine with normal application launch.
Maybe some configurations are wrong?

How to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: do you really need that webpack? angular apps contain a lot of build logic as well as serving logic out of the box. just cal `npm start` in your created angular folder

Comment: I need it for further integration with another service

Comment: please, provide more context

Comment: the application will be used by another service, for this you need to pack it into one file. What context are we talking about?